# Can I declare many-to-many through an intermediate model on both of the related models, so I can take advantage of the automatic ModelForm?

Tags: django, many-to-many

This is my code:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    [...]

class Theme(models.Model):
    [...]
    resource_set = models.ManyToManyField(Resource, through='Match', related_name='theme_set', blank=True)

class Match(models.Model):
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource)
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme)
    [...]
```

I am intentionally using an intermediate model, because I want to add some attributes to the relationship. Now... I know that when declaring many-to-many relationship in Theme, I am also getting a reverse relationship from Resource. See the related_name I'm using? This way I have "symmetrical" field names in both models (resource_set, theme_set, and match_set in both models).

My problem is that when I generate forms from both models (Resource and Theme) they are not symmetrical. When I generate a Theme form I automatically get a multiple choice field to choose from the already existing Resources. But when I generate a Resource form I don't.

**So that is why I would like to declare many-to-many relationship in both models - to make them really equal (not like in the Pizzas and Toppings example ;) and to have these additional multiple choice fields generated.
The question is - is it possible, or do I have to add the multiple choice field to the ResourceForm myself or use FormSets which I don't understand yet?**

BTW - as I can't save a new Theme from ThemeForm using save() ("Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.") I do this:

```
[...]
theme = form.save(commit=False)
theme.save()
for resource in form.cleaned_data['resource_set']:
    match = Match()
    match.resource = resource
    match.theme = theme
    match.save()
return redirect([...]
```

Comment: You probably can't add it in Resource's model, so it's more a Form issue. Have you tried adding `fields = ('themes',)` (or something like that) in `class Meta` in `class ThemeForm`?

Comment: I have tried adding something like:
   `add_to_themes = ModelMultipleChoiceField(Theme.objects.all(), required=False)`
field to the ResourceForm. It seems to do the trick, but... I want to make sure there is no more straighforward way of making these models 'equal'. I would hope to have code in both views (for adding Resource and adding Theme) almost identical.

Actually I would rather add such fields manually to both forms instead of adding it just to ResourceForm, while having it automatically appear in ThemeForm.

Comment: What I am aiming for is to have two models in a many-to-many relationship (through intermediate model) but on "equal terms".
If you see the example here: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships) it say's " it's more natural to think about a pizza having toppings than a topping being on multiple pizzas". In my case, themes and resources are supposed to be naturally equal.

Comment: (of course I meant `class ResourceForm`) IMHO there isn't a better way than making the other "leg" yourself, as you're doing with the `add_to_themes` field. I don't think there is a quick way in Django to make things perfectly symmetrical

Comment: `"it's more natural to think about a pizza having toppings than a topping being on multiple pizzas"`

@pmeus So is it more natural for you to have resources with multiple themes, or with themes that can apply to multiple resources?

Comment: @Thomas As I said in my comment above - in my case, themes and resources are supposed to be naturally equal :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define it on both sides.

One problem would be the related_name - As far as I know, there is no way of telling the ORM "I'll take care of the reverse relation myself". So you'll need to change the related_names so they don't clash with the real field names. In this example I added underscore to the related_names, so Resource objects now have both theme_set and _theme_set, which are two handles to the same data.

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    [...]
    theme_set = models.ManyToManyField('Theme',
        through='Match', 
        related_name='_resource_set', 
        blank=True)

class Theme(models.Model):
    [...]
    resource_set = models.ManyToManyField(Resource,
        through='Match',
        related_name='_theme_set',
        blank=True)
```

Also, if you're using South, you may need to [add_ignored_fields](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customfields.html#field-name-patterns) to one of the field.

Comment: Thanks. There was not much feedback, so I've decided to leave it as it was. I have declared the relation in Resource model and modified the ThemeForm as mentioned in [my comment here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429457/can-i-declare-many-to-many-through-an-intermediate-model-on-both-of-the-related#comment20087881_14429457)

It did the trick and I haven't had any problems with it since then. The results are here: [thematick](http://thematick.zrobmy.to/)